# Reset a previously selected row and highlight a new row in inlinenav JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to reset a previously selected row and highlight a new row in inlinenav JQGrid. Please help..

```
var lastSel = null;
function onSelectRow(id) {
if (lastSel != id) {
    $("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel, function () { });
    //$('#ProgramListGird').jqGrid('resetSelection', lastSel, true); 
    lastSel = id;
}
$("programListGird").setSelection(id);
editparameters = {
    "keys": false,
    "oneditfunc": null,
    "successfunc": null,
    "url": null,
    "extraparam": {},
    "aftersavefunc": null,
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc": null,
    "restoreAfterError": true,
    "mtype": "POST"
}
$("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid('editRow', id, editparameters);   
 }
```

//$('#ProgramListGird').jqGrid('resetSelection', lastSel, true);  - if i use this line of code then my restore functionality is not working. Means that, on each row select the rows are getting in to edit mode but not restored which is actually a wrong behavior. Please help..

Comment: Can you describe some context? What are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to put something into the clipboard on the server side?

Comment: i have my view page, i just want to copy to clipboard the text which is in my view page.

Comment: Don't use the clipboard on a web server, it does not do anything useful.  Always keep in mind that the web server and the user's browser run on different machines.

Comment: You want to make it available in the clipboard for the user who is displaying your page in the browser?

Comment: @ Hans Passant: ok thanks. Is there anyother way to achieve this.

Comment: You are probably looking for a JavaScript solution to copy the text to the Clip Board.

Comment: Please, read this SO thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) it should help in your scenario.

Comment: @ Håkan Fahlstedt: yes, but i tried to do this in my code in controller,

Comment: @Håkan Fahlstedt:Could you please tell me, Is that possible to do this in javascript?

Comment: Check out the link that sszarek posted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Adding [STAThread] Attribute to your method solves the problem.
For example:

```
[STAThread]
private void f() 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access OLE functions (like copy to clipboard) you need a single thread application.

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    ...        
}
```

But maybe this can help you along [ZeroClipboard for copy to clipboard in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069205/zeroclipboard-for-copy-to-clipboard-in-asp-net-mvc)...